# Google Cloud SQL API - Error 401 when trying to patch a new IP address with cURL

Tags: php, curl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, service-accounts

I have the following code in order to add an new authorized address into Google Cloud SQL with cURL :

```
$access_token = "[Removed for security reasons]";
$headers = array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token, 'Content-Type: application/json');

$send_method = "PATCH";
$payload = '{"settings" : {"ipConfiguration" : {"authorizedNetworks" : [{ "value": "220.20.0.1" }]}}}';


$settings = array(
     CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $send_method,
     CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
     CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
     CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
     CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $payload
);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($curl, ($settings));

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

I know that my payload is OK because it works on https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/patch .

I also know that the token is good because I got it from the oAuth playground (https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground).
I use a service account and I set myself as the owner of it.

Nevertheless, I get the following error (I also get it into the oAuth playground) :

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

What can I do?